# OAuth 2.0 , Open ID connect, and SAML

Tags: java, oauth, single-sign-on, saml, openid-connect

I need to develop a SSO server for my client. My use case is that, i have two application and i want them not to have their own login screen, and to make it easy to user to jump from App 1 to App 2(App 1 and App 2 hold their own resources, and they should depend on the central authentication server only to authenticate and authorize the user). I was reading about creating SSO server in java. I started reading about oauth 2.0, open ID connect , and SAML. The more i read, the more i get confused.

Some places i have read that Oauth 2.0 cannot be used for SSO, and some place i read that it can be used.

I am some understanding on how these three works. Yet, I am unable to visualize how these three differ from each other.

I will put my question up below

1. Can Oauth 2.0 used for SSO
2. Which one is better b/w Oauth 2.0 , SAML , and Open ID connect for a financial corporation, whose data is very sensitive. Also we are intended to have native mobile apps as well. Which will also use this same SSO Server to log in users.
3. Is there any library to implement any one of these in java. I am intended to use dropwizard server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrt. to "1. Can OAuth be used for SSO" there's a very good read here: http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/ which basically says: "not without an extension profile, and that is done already as a standard profile called OpenID Connect"

Answer (score 1):

OAuth does not provide true SSO in the Federation sense e.g. using WS-Federation / SAML and a Security Token Service (STS).

OAuth is actually an authorization protocol i.e. used for consent. OpenID Connect provides an authentication layer on top of OAuth.

SAML is the "best" choice e.g. Shibboleth, Salesforce, WorkDay etc. all use it for SSO.

However, SAML is not suited to native applications because it's browser based using HTTP POST. OAuth is a better fit for this.

For Java SAML, you can use [OpenSAML](https://shibboleth.net/products/opensaml-java.html).

There is an OAuth stack in Spring Security.

Comment: So I assume that Open ID Connect is best choice (Considering Native Mobile Apps)

Comment: Consider using an existing STS that supports both. SimpleSAMLphp supports SAML, OAuth and OpenID Connect and is free.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the Chairman of CAS and founder of CAS in the cloud (https://www.casinthecloud.com).

CAS is also a widely used SSO solution. It works for websites and mobile applications and has some powerful features like the gateway, renew and proxy.
It's really an easy protocol you can understand and integrate with very quickly. There are many CAS clients in many technologies to work with the CAS server.
It's open source and free, or you can rely on a paid provider if you prefer.